# When is Synctex file written?

Tags: luatex, forward-inverse-search

When is the syncTeX file written and is there a way to get a callback in to lua after it occurs? I would like to read it at the end of the compilation process rather than have to compile twice to get at it.

I could potentially run an external script or wrap the compilation process to accomplish this task but that is much more work than necessary.

finish_pdffile  occurs before synctex is written so it is no good ;/

Here is a list of all the callbacks, I believe, I don't see anything that will help.

```
local callbacktypes = callbacktypes or {
  find_read_file     = exclusive,
  find_write_file    = exclusive,
  find_font_file     = data,
  find_output_file   = data,
  find_format_file   = data,
  find_vf_file       = data,
  find_map_file      = data,
  find_enc_file      = data,
  find_sfd_file      = data,
  find_pk_file       = data,
  find_data_file     = data,
  find_opentype_file = data,
  find_truetype_file = data,
  find_type1_file    = data,
  find_image_file    = data,
  open_read_file     = exclusive,
  read_font_file     = exclusive,
  read_vf_file       = exclusive,
  read_map_file      = exclusive,
  read_enc_file      = exclusive,
  read_sfd_file      = exclusive,
  read_pk_file       = exclusive,
  read_data_file     = exclusive,
  read_truetype_file = exclusive,
  read_type1_file    = exclusive,
  read_opentype_file = exclusive,
  find_cidmap_file   = data,
  read_cidmap_file   = exclusive,
  process_input_buffer  = data,
  process_output_buffer = data,
  process_jobname       = data,
  contribute_filter      = simple,
  buildpage_filter       = simple,
  pre_linebreak_filter   = list,
  linebreak_filter       = list,
  append_to_vlist_filter = list,
  post_linebreak_filter  = list,
  hpack_filter           = list,
  vpack_filter           = list,
  hpack_quality          = list,
  vpack_quality          = list,
  pre_output_filter      = list,
  process_rule           = list,
  hyphenate              = simple,
  ligaturing             = simple,
  kerning                = simple,
  insert_local_par       = simple,
  mlist_to_hlist         = list,
  pre_dump             = simple,
  start_run            = simple,
  stop_run             = simple,
  start_page_number    = simple,
  stop_page_number     = simple,
  show_error_hook      = simple,
  show_warning_message = simple,
  show_error_message   = simple,
  show_lua_error_hook  = simple,
  start_file           = simple,
  stop_file            = simple,
  finish_pdffile = data,
  finish_pdfpage = data,
  define_font = exclusive,
}
```

I'm also not sure of a pure lua way or if the synctex file is written after all lua code is finished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the source the synctex file is closed as the really last thing after all callbacks

```c
    /* Close {\sl Sync\TeX} file and write status */
    synctexterminate(log_opened_global);       /* Let the {\sl Sync\TeX} controller close its files. */
    free_text_codes();
    free_math_codes();
    if (log_opened_global) {
        wlog_cr();
        selector = selector - 2;
        if ((selector == term_only) && (callback_id == 0)) {
            tprint_nl("Transcript written on ");
            tprint_file_name(NULL, texmf_log_name, NULL);
            print_char('.');
            print_ln();
        }
        lua_a_close_out(log_file);
    }
}
```

which is the end of `close_files_and_terminate` and the only thing called after that is `do_final_end();` which just sets the error status and stops.

So I don't think the synctex data is reliably available during the current run.

Comment: Ok, kinda sucks but I should be able to work around it. Where does one go to do a feature request for lualatex? Also, is synctex part of the lualatex engine(include as source) or a separate build? It would be nice to have a few hooks for lualatex as synctex is doing it's thing. I'm having to extract page numbers and line numbers to do what I want, but having to jump through many hoops to do so...

Comment: @AbstractDissonance that was the source of luatex that I showed. You could ask on luatex list for feature requests (luatex  at tug dot org)  but I would guess you would need to supply a lot more coherent use case than you have so far posted here. Not my call though: I have no write access to those sources:-)